# Jquery ui after confirm dialog go to ajax post

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I delete my record with an ajax $post call in this way

HTML

```
$btn = "<input type='button' ";
$btn .= "url='$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]' idric='$row[id_ric]' ancor='#LR'";
$btn .= "class='deletr ttip' />";
```

JQUERY

```
  $(".delete").click(function(){

       var ancor = $(this).attr('ancor');
       var url = $(this).attr('url');
       var idric = $(this).attr('idric');

       var url = url + ancor;

    $.post("testpost.php", {url:url, idric:idric}, function(data){

         location.reload();

    });
});
```

testpost.ph

```
//class delete
$obj->delete($_POST['id_ric']);
```

I'd like to delete a record after confirming with a dialog box. 
I tried in this way but with no success.

```
  $(".delete").click(function(){

    html_msg = "Are u sure?";

    var ancor = $(this).attr('ancor');
    var url = $(this).attr('url');
    var idric = $(this).attr('idric');

    var url = url + ancor;

    $('#confirm').dialog('open').html(html_msg);
  });

  $("#confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        dialogClass: 'confirm',
        buttons: {
            Yes: function() {
              $(this).dialog( "close" );
             testdelete();
        },
            No: function() {
              $(this).dialog( "close" );

        }
     }
});

function testdelete(){

 $.post("testpost.php", {url:url, idric:idric}, function(data){

    //location.reload();
    alert("ok");

});

}
```

How could I do this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `url` and `idric` as local variables in the `delete` click event.  remove the `var` infront of them and it should work.  Currently the `testdelete` function doesn't know what `url` and `idric` are.

```
  $(".delete").click(function(){

    html_msg = "Are u sure?";

    var ancor = $(this).attr('ancor');
    url = $(this).attr('url');
    idric = $(this).attr('idric');

    url = url + ancor;

    $('#confirm').dialog('open').html(html_msg);
  });

  $("#confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        dialogClass: 'confirm',
        buttons: {
            Yes: function() {
              $(this).dialog( "close" );
             testdelete();
        },
            No: function() {
              $(this).dialog( "close" );

        }
     }
});

function testdelete(){

 $.post("testpost.php", {url:url, idric:idric}, function(data){

    //location.reload();
    alert("ok");

});
```

Comment: making those variables global is generally _not_ an appropriate fix.

Comment: @Alnitak Whilst I agree with you and recommend the OP to perhaps namespace their variables it does however remedy the problem.  @Paolo Rossi You could inline the declaration of the dialog and then call `testdelete` without making the variables global by passing them as arguments as sort of indicated by @Chinnu R

Comment: Is it possible to pass also function name to confirm function (testdelete)?

Comment: Yes but you will still need to give it access to the `url` and `idric` values somehow.  Either inline or via some sort of global reference.

Comment: I will make a fiddle for you.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Sorry.. I tried to set var funcname = 'testdelete' and in the confirm dialog i tried to do - funcname(url, idric), but the function not called. How could I do this? thank a lot

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40119/discussion-between-rob-schmuecker-and-paolo-rossi)